# Where does this approximation comes from

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to understand what approximation is used in this step:

$$ \cos{\theta} \quad=\quad \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+ \frac{R^2}{f^2} }} \quad\approx\quad 1 - \frac{R^2}{2f^2} $$

Any tips?

Comment: Context would be helpful

Comment: $(1+x)^a\sim 1+ax$

Comment: Look for General Binomial approximation ,see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x)^n=\binom n01+\binom n2x+\binom n3x^2+\cdots+\binom nnx^n$$so when $x$ is small enough , you can approx $(1+x)^n\sim 1+nx$
now (It seems $f\gg R$ larger eonugh) so:
$$  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1+ \frac{R^2}{f^2} }}=\\(1+ \frac{R^2}{f^2} )^\frac{-1}{2}\\ \sim 1+\frac{-1}{2} \times \frac{R^2}{f^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

There are two:

$$\frac{1}{1+x} = 1-x+x^2-x^3+... \approx 1-x$$
$$(1+x)^2=1+2x+x^2 \approx 1+2x \implies \sqrt{1+2x} \approx 1+x$$

Both approximations only apply for small values of $x$ (where $x^2$, $x^3$, ... keep on getting smaller and smaller).